# How to implement retry policy based on HTML reponse content?

Tags: c#, polly

I am using WebClient to read some html content from a website using System.Net.WebClient class. Sometime that website gives me 200 response with title tag that says that call limit is exceed and I should retry after few seconds. What I am looking for is some Retry policy that reads that reads that title tag and checks for that call limit exceed error. If that error is present, it should retry. Here is the sample code that's making that call to the website

```
        using (var wc = new GZipWebClient())
        {
            // this html sometimes contain <title> with error message
            html = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
        }
```

I would really appreciate if someone can provide a sample code about how to implement a retry logic using Polly for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) as you normally would and throw a custom exception when you get an error in the html. Simple example below.

```
    private async Task DownloadAsync()
    {
       using (var wc = new GZipWebClient())
       {
          // this html sometimes contain <title> with error message
          html = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

          if (html.Contains("My Error Message")) 
          {
              // Log Error
              throw new MyDownloadFailedException(html);
          }
      }
   }

   // In your calling method
   var p = Policy
            .Handle<MyDownloadFailedException>()
            .RetryForever(exception =>  
            {
                // log.Warning("Failed, retrying....");
            });

   p.ExecuteAsync(async() => await DownloadAsync());
```

Comment: Thanks.... I tried that but it doesn't seem like it's executing that web call at all (not even throwing Exception)

Comment: Updated the answer to a better example

Comment: Also added a link to the Polly documentation

Answer (score 2):

Polly policies can [handle results natively](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-1b-optionally-specify-return-results-you-want-to-handle), as well as exceptions.  There is no need to make the code executed through the policy throw an exception, to trigger a retry.

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<string>(s => s.Contains("whatever text triggers retry")) // or whatever more complicated predicate you want
    .Retry...Async(...); // whatever flavour of retry overload you want

private async Task DownloadAsync()
{
   using (var wc = new GZipWebClient())
   {
      // this html sometimes contain <title> with error message
      html = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
   }
}
```

A single policy instance can handle both exceptions and results, so exception-handling could also be combined into the policy above.

---

If the response from the API called also includes information about *how long* to wait before retrying ("RetryAfter"), then Polly also provides [specific patterns allowing you to construct a policy which automatically waits for exactly the retry-after time specified in the response](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait).